# Antec VP450 power supply doesn't power on

Tags: power-supply

I have a 3 year old [Antec VP450](http://www.antec.com/product.php?id=704902&pid=12&lan=us) PSU. It has a power switch behind it which I always switch off after shutting down my PC. This PC is connected to an APC UPS.

Yesterday I shutdown the PC and left without turning off this switch and the UPS was also left on. I came back after two hours and pressed the power button on the PC and it didn't power up.

After doing all the regular troubleshooting I opened the cabinet unplugged all the power cables and shorted the green and a black wire in 24pin connector. The SMPS didn't power on.

I found this from the [official manual](http://store.antec.com/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=148).

> Sometimes the PSU will “latch” into a protected state. You will need to power off the PSU and clear the fault before it will function again.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Yes, It happened while trying to rebuild a pc in a hurry. I shorted a 5V pin and the short circuit protection kicked in. You have to unplug the PSU, wait a couple of minutes and power on again. But, IMHO, this doesn't apply in your case

Comment: Unplug everything, wait about an hour, and plug directly into the wall without the UPC and see if this works.

Comment: Your product link is dead (no longer available).