# Power Supply turns off 10 seconds after power on

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

I have an Antec VP450 PSU. Today when I switched on my PC it turned off right before Windows loaded. I narrowed down the issue to this PSU, removed it and tested it by shorting the green wire in the ATX connector. The PSU fan spun for around 10 seconds and stopped. This happened every time I tried turning it on and I'm unable to get the PSU to work continuously.

- Is the PSU dead? It is slightly less than 3 years old.
- Is this model (Antec VP450) known to fail? I had the same model previously [which also died](https://superuser.com/q/881502/353597) after 3 years.
- If I get a new PSU which of these would last longer? A 650W 80+ standard PSU or a 550W 80+ gold PSU? My PC doesn't need more than 400W as per outervision's calculator.

Answer (score 1):

With your test shorting the green wire, you've effectively narrowed down the failing component to the PSU.  Good job, not everyone knows how to do that.

I don't have any knowledge about that model, but if this is your 2nd that died in under 3 years, then move to another brand or model.

PSUs produce less power as they age.  If your system needs 400W and you have a 450W PSU, then you only have a 50W difference between full power and potential damage to your components by under powering them.  Yes, this is a thing.

Generally, I don't put less than a 650W PSU in even a basic computer.  With your system needing 400W, this gives you plenty of headroom for the PSU to slowly fail over time, as well as room to grow (CPU, GPU, or RAM upgrades, more HDs, etc.).

Electronics only pull as much power as they need, so your system will only pull 400W.  You don't have to worry about the PSU "pushing" 650w (or whatever you choose), since it doesn't work like that.

Also, a PSU tends to be more efficient the farther away you are from it's max wattage.  This happens because you are putting less stress on the components.  Putting less stress on the PSU also helps is age more gracefully.

My recommendation is to get a 650W 80 PLUS Bronze or higher wattage PSU.  The difference between the 80 PLUS levels is minimal, but I figure Bronze level uses better parts.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_Plus

EDIT: If you have the same issue with the new PSU, look into getting a power conditioning UPS.  There may be something with your incoming power that is frying your PSUs.

Comment: Actually 400W is the "Recommended PSU Wattage" suggested by Outervision and not the load wattage.

Comment: I'd never run across that site before, so I did a test.  The made up system I gave it rated at 420W at load, 470 for a recommended PSU wattage, then recommended a 700W 80 PLUS Bronze PSU.  They seem to be working on the same/similar principle I am.  Even if they weren't, I'd still stand by my recommendation.